# Wave Interfernce of sub-atomic particles

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

We know that sub-atomic charged particles, proton and electron, emit EM radiation as they are constantly vibrating.

Do these particles having equal and opposite charges emit EM radiation in wave form in different direction of amplitude from each other?

Comment: subatomic particles do NOT emit EM radiation because they are constantly vibrating.   A non-accelerating electron does not emit EM radiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consider vibrating a superposed electron and proton in unison. You would effectively be vibrating a neutral particle, from which no EM radiation would be emitted. This means the electric and magnetic fields must be equal and opposite.

Comment: And both are emitted isotropically in every direction perpendicular to the one of the oszillation.

Comment: The case you presented happens in isolated atom if uniformly disturbed charge, right? In normal atom, the EM radiation will be there due to slightly different phases of waves. Am I correct?

Comment: @Anubis A stable atom does not emit radiation, if it did the electron would quickly decay into the nucleus.

Comment: @jamie1989 If that is the case, then how does neutral object emit EM radiation?

Comment: @Anubis As stated in my answer, em radiation is not emitted by vibrating a neutral object.

Comment: @jamie1989 So when iron which is neutral is in its molten state which is also neutral although much more hotter, it is visible even in the dark thus concludes that it emits EM radiation. So how to you explain this?

Comment: @ Anubis this is a slightly different scenario than the one depicted in the answer. Of course you can vibrate the electron, exciting it to a higher energy level within the atom or bulk material, from which em radiation will subsequently be emitted.